# How to to fetch all attributes of user from Active Directory using java code

Tags: java

I want to fetch all attributes of particular user from active directory using java code. For ex: If I give input a email id(abc@gmail.com), then how could I fetch all the attributes of the user having email id as abc@gmail.com

I am new to JNDI API. Please help me out..

Comment: Try with below suggested code. add some additional fields at last of the code

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code:

```
private static String ldapUrl = "ladp//url:port";
    private  static String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static String securityAuthType = "simple";
    private static String securityPrincipal = "your service account";
    private static String securityCredentials="password";




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {            
              Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, securityAuthType);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, securityCredentials);

            DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);

            SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
            ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            NamingEnumeration enumeration = context.search("dc=xxx,dc=com", query, ctrl);

            while (enumeration.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) enumeration.next();

                Attributes attribs = result.getAttributes();
                System.out.println("Attributes:"+attribs);
                NamingEnumeration<String> attribsIDs = attribs.getIDs();
               System.out.println(attribsIDs);
                // loop on attributes
                StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
                int iAttr = 0;
                while (attribsIDs.hasMore()) {

                    String attrID = attribsIDs.next();
                    System.out.println("AttributeId:"+ iAttr+" "+attrID);
                    NamingEnumeration values = ((BasicAttribute) attribs.get(attrID)).getAll();
                System.out.println("Naming Enumertaion Values"+ values);
```

Comment: Is this code useful to you or you need any additional information ?